# Can't get my div to fade OUT when I scroll to top

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I've found a script to change opacity on scroll and modified it a bit. The div fades **IN** fine, but I can't seem to reverse the fade when I get back to the top.

I can get the browser to "alert" me when it's reached the top, but the opacity part isn't firing, can't seem to figure out why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each(function(i) {

      var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 500);
      }

      /*attempt to fade it out*/
      var scrollPosition = $("body, html").scrollTop();
      if (scrollPosition == 0) {
        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '0'
        }, 500);
      }

    });

  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 2000px;
}

#container DIV {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.hideme {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div>Hello</div>
  <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>


</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkars0yu/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code have several issue:

1. Move `bottom_of_window` out of `each`
2. No need to plus `bottom_of_object` or `bottom_of_window` to anything, just need a little `offset` for example `+100` for `bottom_of_window`
3. And for `fadeOut` just use `else` condition.
4. Instead of `$("body, html").scrollTop();` use `$(window).scrollTop()`
5. And when you use `animation` in this case, you better use `stop()` for prevent conflict between `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effect.

with some changes, here you go:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + 100;
  $('.hideme').each(function(i) {
    var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top;
    if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
      $(this).stop().animate({
        'opacity': '1'
      }, 500);
    } else {
      $(this).stop().animate({
        'opacity': '0'
      }, 500);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 2000px;
}

#container div {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.hideme {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div>Hello</div>
  <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
  <div class="hideme">Fade In 2</div>
  <div class="hideme">Fade In 3</div>

</div>
```

And you can use `fadeIn(500)` or `fadeOut(500)` instead of `$(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);`

Comment: Thank you @Mr. X. I had actually removed the body, html thing but someone edited my question and it made it back in somehow. With some changes to the offset I was able to get this working on my site the way I wanted, Cheers!